# Schengen visa refused for the second time

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals

My second Schengen visa application was denied again within two days. I applied with my whole family (mother, sister, grandmother, and me), me and my sister had employment leave letters and all other stuff, but only my mother has ties in our home country, we don't have. The embassy gave the same reason again for the refusal. Please help me. What are the other documents I need to submit?

The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intend stay was not reliable.

- Your intention to leave territory of the member states before the expiry of the visa could not be ascertained.

Comment: With two applications rejected in two days, you've probably set yourself up for having any other application in the near future denied on the tiniest reason they can find. When your whole family is going your making it harder to provide ties to your home country, but that is what they want.

Answer (score 2):

They do not believe that you are a genuine tourist.

- Having a job is good, but it is not enough. Is your **salary** high enough that no reasonable person would quit your job and overstay in the Schengen area?
- Do your travel plans fit your **disposable income**? Most people spend only a small part of their income on tourism.

You ask what *documents* you have to provide, but that may be the wrong question. Your *personal situation* has to be stable enough, then documents will not be a problem.